# GMAP 3 Plugin for JQuery. Change the Marker Position?

Tags: jquery, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-gmap3

I am using the GMAP 3 plugin for JQuery on my website.
I want to re-position the Marker to point to this [place](http://goo.gl/maps/zPD5u).

The Code is [Here](http://pastebin.com/JLKC8XZe).
Due to limitation of the number of characters, I am posting the Code in Pastebin.

Anyone who has used this plugin before and knows how to re-position the map marker to point to a particular place?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still have issues with this but that should be the simplest of all usage of the plugin:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#IdOfYourMapDivContainer').gmap3({
           map:{
              options:{
                  center: [17.435939, 78.341678],
                  zoom: 8
              }
           },
           marker:{
              latLng: [17.435939, 78.341678]
           }
        });
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the implementation. The change was to be done in the main JS file where the GMAP3 was finally called.

Comment: Great thanks! Become insane by trying using position variable from documentation. With latLng work fine.